# How do you uninstall the OSX documentation in XCode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have installed the iOS documentation in XCode 4, but I don't want the OSX documentation. Is it possible to remove it or choose not to install it?

On machine I keep hitting cancel to the install dialog that pops up randomly for the OSX docs but this is annoying. On my other machine I did install the OSX documentation but I really want to uninstall it as it just clogs up the documentation browser with mostly duplicated information.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can easily hide the OS X doc sets from the documentation browser without uninstalling them. In the Xcode 4 documentation browser, click the little arrow next to the magnifying glass in the search box and select Show Find Options. Then deselect from the Doc Sets popup all the items you are not interested in (namely, Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library).

Comment: Does this still work in Xcode 5? I'm getting OS X documentation when I'm trying to search for iOS documentation and I have the magnifying glass drop down already set to iOS.

Answer (score 14):

You can uninstall documentation by simply dragging it to the trash in the Finder. It's located in this folder:

iPhone: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets`
Mac OS: `/Developer/Documentation/DocSets`

I wanted to do this to free up disk space on a small laptop HD.

Comment: It probably won't, since you can still use the online documentation through the docs browser.

Comment: With Xcode 4.4+ where Xcode is an app bundle, the docs are in ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/ for iOS and /Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/ but you can remove them in Xcode now by opening the Xcode Preferences > Downloads and selecting the documentation you wish to remove and clicking the [-] button.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I was going to add the bit about the [-] remove button in Xcode 4.3 but that button doesn't actually work in that version of Xcode.

Comment: Andrew, you should move your comment to a separate answer.

Comment: Andrew please could you make that an answer. Also, for non Apple docs, it's necessary to move to trash as they aren't shown in the Xcode Downloads.